# DataServiceContext don't read related entities into the entity object

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api, wcf-data-services

I'm making a call to an OData V3 WebApi, expanding some related entities as follow:

```
var cenarioInvestimentoEscolhido = Container.CenarioDeInvestimentoEscolha.Expand("CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario,CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario/Cenario,CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario/Aeronave").Where(c => c.CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario.CenarioDeInvestimento.Aerodromo.CodigoIcao.Equals(idAerodromo)).SingleOrDefault();
```

This is the Absolute URI generated by the expression:

```
https://localhost/SAC/WebAPI/ODataWebApi/CenarioDeInvestimentoEscolha()?$filter=CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario/CenarioDeInvestimento/Aerodromo/CodigoIcao%20eq%20'SNBR'&$top=2&$expand=CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario,CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario/Cenario,CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario/Aeronave
```

And this is the result set responded by the API:

```
{
    "odata.metadata":"https://localhost/SAC/WebAPI/ODataWebApi/$metadata#CenarioDeInvestimentoEscolha","value":[
      {
          "CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario":{
              "Aeronave":{
                  "Id":4,"Codigo":"B738","Nome":"737-800","IdFabricante":3,"Pmd":"80-90%","Categoria":"4C"
              },"Cenario":{
                  "Id":3,"Nome":"Cen\u00e1rio 3"
              },"IdAerodromo":112,"IdCenario":3,"IdAeronave":4,"CategoriaDeAeronave":"4C","Subtotal":"39587651.01","EventualAcrescimo":"3958765.10","Total":"43546416.11"
          },"IdAerodromo":112,"IdCenario":3,"DataInformadoBancoBrasil":"2014-03-11T00:00:00","NumeroOficio":"46/2014/SEAP/SAC-PR","DataEscolhaSalaMonitoramento":"2014-03-17T00:00:00","DataEscolhaSacpr":"2014-03-18T00:00:00"
      }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, there is an entity named **CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario** with related entities **Aeronave** and **Cenario**.
Howevar, both child entites are null after this call, as if they're not deserializated.

I already checked the response stream in the ReceivingResponse event and indeed the related information has been received. Why those properties are null? Is this some serialization issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this attribute above your controller action ?

```
[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = X)]
```

Comment: I already checked the response stream in the ReceivingResponse event and indeed the related information has been received